# Poincaré’s inequality in dimension one with mixed boundary conditions

Tags: inequality, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose that $u$ is $C^1$ in $[0,\pi/2]$ and $u(0)=u’(\pi/2)=0$. I want to derive the following Poincaré inequality
$$
\int_0^{\pi/2} u(x)^2\,dx \leq \int_0^{\pi/2} u’(x)^2\,dx.
$$

Since $u(0)=0$, we have that $u(x) = \int_0^x u’(s)\,ds$. Hence
\begin{align}
u^2(x) & \leq \biggl( \int_0^x u’(s)\,dx\biggr)^2 \\
       & \leq x\int_0^x u’(s)^2\,ds
\end{align}
by Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. It follows that
\begin{align}
\int_0^{\pi/2} u^2(x)\,dx
& \leq \int_0^{\pi/2} \int_0^x xu’(s)^2\,ds\,dx \\
& = \int_0^{\pi/2} \int_s^{\pi/2} xu’(s)^2\,dx\,ds \\
& = \int_0^{\pi/2} \biggl(\frac{\pi^2}{8} - \frac{s^2}{2}\biggr) u’(s)^2\,ds \\
& \leq \frac{\pi^2}{8} \int_0^{\pi/2} u’(s)^2\,ds.
\end{align}

As you can see, the constant $1$ (better than $\pi^2/8$) can not be obtained by using only the condition $u(0)=0$.

My question is how to utilize the other boundary condition $u’(\pi/2)=0$ to derive this better constant. I have seen this conclusion in one paper and the author said that the constant can be obtained by considering the eigenvalue problem

\begin{cases}
-u’’ = \lambda u \\
u(0)=u’(\pi/2)=0
\end{cases}

and calculating that $1$ is the minimal eigenvalue of the above equation. What’s the principle behind this?